# Google Chrome Extensions: How to include jQuery in programmatically injected content script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm injecting my *content script* from the *background page* when the user clicks the *browser action* button, like so:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });
});
```

So how can I access jQuery from inside my `content.js`? I don't see a way to inject that simultaneously.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

What about:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "content.js" });
});
```

You can download "jquery.js" from here: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: That'll throw them into the same "isolated world"? I'll give it a whirl!

Comment: Hah! Brilliant. Works! Thank you :D

Comment: But...what if you're using the hosted jQuery at googleapis.com?

Comment: @Aerovistae You may as well just download it, it would be faster as well as safer. And **serg**, so simple yet so effective! Brilliant solution!

Comment: `$` is still not defined.

Answer (score 16):

How about adding this to your manifest file

```
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "js": [
                "jquery.js", 
                "contentscript.js"
            ]
    }
],
```

Comment: Wouldn't this make Chrome to parse jQuery in every tab even when it's not needed?

Comment: @ManuelFaux yes. You would need to add a "matches" property that controls the domains that it would execute jQuery on.

Comment: Where do I find this "jquery.js"?

Comment: @Daniel you have to download it (https://code.jquery.com/), name it "jquery.js" and leave it in the same directory if you want to use his exact code

Comment: This answer is not the solution to the question. The asker needs a programmatic injection (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi), which is triggered by a click on the browser action button, not on every single page that matches the pattern in the manifest file.

Comment: I needed to use jq on all pattern matched pages so i fixed it like this http://prntscr.com/evhfj2

Answer (score 5):

UPDATE:

Execute second script after the first one would be more accurate in terms of script order, `result` is an array of results of execution of the script in list of tabs.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:'js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'}, function(result){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:'js/myscript.js'});
});
```

OLD:

Injecting Jquery followed by your script will gives ability to access Jquery within your script.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:'js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file:'js/myscript.js'});
```

You have more control over how the script should be injected as described in [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript). Specially `allFrames` property is important if you wish to inject script to all the frames within the document. Ignoring it will only injected into the top frame. Since it is not mentioned in other answers guess it helps you. Scripts can be injected always by adding it to manifest as described [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration).

Comment: Yes, but you should use the callback of the first one to inject the second one.  Otherwise, they could finish executing in the wrong order, which would be difficult to debug.

Comment: @Teepeemm yeah, that would be the correct solution. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Since I've much scripts with many dependencies , I use a function `concatenateInjection` that takes three parameters:

```
//id: the tab id to pass to executeScript
//ar: an array containing scripts to load ( index order corresponds to execution order)
//scrpt (opzional): the last script to execute (if not provided, than the last script is the last insert in previous array)

function concatenateInjections(id, ar, scrpt){
  var i = ar.length;
  var idx = 0;

  function inject(idx){
    idx++;
    if(idx <= i){
      var f = ar[idx-1];
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, { file: f }, function() {
          inject(idx);
      });
    }else{
      if(typeof scrpt === 'undefined') return;
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, { file: scrpt });
    }
  }
  inject(idx);
}
```

and usage example:

```
// id is tab id

// sources: first execute jquery, than default.js and anime.js in the end
var def = [
  "lib/jquery-1.11.3.min.js", 
  "lib/default.js", 
  "injection/anime.js"
];

// run concatenate injections
concatenateInjections(id, def);
```

Think that's could be useful.

### UPDATE

Version with concat and closure (more aesthetic):

```
function concatenateInjections(id, ar, scrpt){

  if( typeof scrpt !== 'undefined' ) ar = ar.concat([scrpt]);

  var i = ar.length;
  var idx = 0 ;

  (function (){
    var that = arguments.callee;
    idx++;
    if(idx <= i){
      var f = ar[idx-1];
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(id, { file: f }, function(){ that(idx);} );
    }
  })();

}
```

Comment: Because if there's several scripts with same dependencies then i can define a single array "ar" for this depencied and change only the scrpt parameter for each call of "concatenateInject". I'm very lazy ;-)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: I've updated using a `ar.concat(...)`  as suggested by @Xan. Anyway I prefer to maintain `scrpt` parameter, so I dont' have to write `myarray.concat('str')` in `concatenateInjections()`. Remember: I'm very lazy :-)

Comment: It's fine; it's usable code. What I meant is to use it like `concatenateInjections(id, ar.concat(script))` for the use case you present and keep it as 2 arguments.

Answer (score 2):

**Update for manifest v3**

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
target: { tabId: tab.id },
files : [ "jquery.js" ]
}).then(() => chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    function: your_function,
}));
```

Answer (score 1):

anytime you want to dynamically insert jQuery, i recommend this script

i personally have a Chrome Custom Search "`$`" which replaces `$` with

```
javascript:
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.onload = function(){};
jq.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js";
document.querySelector('head').appendChild(jq);
```

`javascript:` is just the way to run javascript from the url bar

i use this on my `about:blank` page when i'm trying to mock up some css situation quickly

Answer (score 1):

Official [documented method](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/migrating/improve-security/#use-external-libraries) of loading external scripts for manifest v3:

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
  target: {tabId: tab.id},
  files: ['jquery-min.js', 'content-script.js']
});
```