# Connect external js lib to chrome event page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

**EDIT** - problem solved. I just not reloaded extension properly after changing my manifest. Shame on me.

I'm trying to connect some libs like JQuery to my background.js in chrome extension. Well, I found lots of tips how to do it, but I receive an error. My manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Chrome WM",
  "version": "0.1",


    "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["http://*/*","https://*/*"],
    "js": [
      "s/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", "s/jquery.soap.js"
    ]
  }],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["s/jquery-1.11.1.min.js", "s/jquery.soap.js", "background.js"],
        "persistent": false
  },

  "permissions": [
        "tabs",
    "activeTab", 
    "http://192.168.10.150:801/*"
  ]
}
```

I probably don't need "content_scripts" section, but just in case.

My background.js:

```
function siteChanged(activeInfo) {

    if (jQuery) {  
    console.log("Jquery on");
    } else {
        console.log("Jquery off");
    }

  // Lots of things here
}

chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(siteChanged);
```

Okay, if I remove this "if (JQuery)" thing whole script works fine, but if not I'm receive such error when event occured:

```
Error in event handler for tabs.onActivated: ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at siteChanged (chrome-extension://flhbfgingimkoknegkcnchnhjdmnhcji/background.js:6:6)
```

There IS jquery-1.11.1.min.js script in s folder relatively background.js file, and if I create html page beside this background script, grab this jquery-1.11.1.min.js and check if it connected properly - all fine.

What I doing wrong?

Comment: As a test, can you take out `"persistent": false` from the manifest?

Comment: yeah, I already tested this :( Works same way

Comment: I don't see any problems with your manifest.. Can you make a minimal example and upload it somewhere?

Comment: https://yadi.sk/d/s9S7ox0MdTSbN There is what I've got for now. If remove "if(JQuery)..." it simply writes in log the latest website and time when it was opened and closed.

Comment: I don't have any problems with your test code, at all, persistent or not. Are you sure you properly reloaded the extension after changing code / adding files?

Comment: Damn... it's works fine. I just disabled extension, press "reload extensions" button and enabled it again and it doesn't worked. Now I just remove it and load again and all fine. Thanks you. Sorry for being stupid)

Comment: "Reload extensions" doesn't do what you expect it to do. It forces as request for updates for all extensions with `update_url` set (for instance, extensions from the Store). To update a local extension in development, use `Reload` on the item itself while it's enabled.

Comment: Thanks! Can you form this as an answer? I'll mark this question as resolved then