# Remote script as content script in Chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to inject a remote script as the content script in Chrome extension, but I feel like I'm running into the murky (at least to me) area of Chrome execution environment.

I want to use jQuery's `$.getScript` for that (and other) purposes.

**Here's the injection code** (brilliantly [suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698118/google-chrome-extensions-how-to-include-jquery-in-programatically-injected-cont)):

```
// inject jQuery
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "js/jquery.js" }, function() {
   // inject remote script with jQuery
   chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: '$.getScript("https://mysite.com/myremotescript.js", function(){ })' });
});
```

**Here's the remote script** `myremotescript.js` - it's simple:

```
$("body").css("backgroundColor", "green");
```

**The error is**: `"$ is not defined"`

The `$` referred in the error seems to be that of the `myremotescript.js` function, because it works if `myremotescript.js` is changed to:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
```

It appears that it's not only `$` that is not defined. If I change `myremotescript.js` to:

```
function Do(){
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```

and then execute Do() from the callback of `$.getScript`:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
    code: '$.getScript("https://mysite.com/myremotescript.js", function(){ Do(); })' 
});
```

The error is then: `"Do is not defined"`

Any ideas/explanation/suggestions?

**EDIT: SOLUTION:** Following **@Rob-W** answer, it worked. The only quirk that I needed to add to get `$.get()` not to error out was to mark the data type as "text". Also, I didn't need to do `eval`, since `executeScript` can accept code-as-text:

```
$.get("https://mysite.com/myremotescript.js", null, null, "text")
    .done(function(remoteCode){
        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: remoteCode }, function(){
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { code: "Do();" });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getScript` defaults to injecting a `<script>` element to load scripts from a different origin. Consequently, the code runs in the context of the page, *not* the content script ([see also](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#execution-environment)).

If you really want to use jQuery to get the script, replace

```js
$.getScript("https://mysite.com/myremotescript.js", function(){ });
```

with the following (`eval` is used as a callback, thus it evaluates the response of the request)

```js
$.get("https://mysite.com/myremotescript.js", eval);
```

While this works, I recommend to cache the script's response body. Then, your extension will not break if the network connection drops. And, more importantly, the user will not get a useless request for every page load. I've fleshed out this concept before, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10371025/938089).

Comment: Thanks Rob. It appears that because I do a cross-domain xhr with `$.get()` it requires me to add permissions with a match pattern (for some reason `$.getScript()` did not require it). Is this, in fact, true? Does it add a special warning to the user during extension installation?

Comment: Just "Can access all data on example.com". See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html

Comment: Yeah... that's kinda crappy, for the user confusion part, if for nothing else. Couldn't I just overcome this by doing `$.getScript` in the background/page, then retrieve the `innerHtml` of the `<script>` tag and apply it to `executeScript`?

Comment: Ah no, I take it back.... it adds a <script> element that points to a remote resource...