# How to programmatically inject jquery code in chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension, deferred-execution, javascript-injection

I have a requirement of inserting following jquery code on click of an extension

```
var klo=$(".dijitAccordionTitle.dijitAccordionTitle-selected").parent().siblings().css("display","none")
$('#containerDiv').show().parentsUntil('body').andSelf().siblings().hide();
$("#dijit_layout_AccordionContainer_0").height($(document).height())
```

Similar concept is explained in "Programmatic injection" of http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html.My issue is that i want to run jquery code instead of plain javascript code.
Thanks

Comment: You have to inject both jQuery and your custom code then. However, since your jQuery code isn't very complicated maybe it will be easier to simply rewrite it in vanilla JS?

Comment: Yes i agree this code is not complicated but its thoroughly tested.Writing it in plain vanilla will again take time:)

Comment: As Konrad said, why don't you just add jQuery to your extension and to the list of content scripts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extensions: How to include jQuery in programatically injected content script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698118/google-chrome-extensions-how-to-include-jquery-in-programatically-injected-cont)