# Include Jquery in a content script of a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

The error message I am receiving is "$ is not defined"

Part of my manifest file:

```
     "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": ["http://www.google.com/calendar/render*",                                          
       "https://www.google.com/calendar/render/*"],
       "js": ["jquery.min.js", "jquery-ui.js", "script.js"],
       "css": ["jquery.datepick.css", "jquery-ui.css"],
       "run_at": "document_start"
     }],
     "background": {"scripts": ["background.js"]},
     "web_accessible_resources": ["jquery.min.js", "script.js", "jquery-ui.js",  "jquery.datepick.css", "jquery-ui.css"]
```

In my background.js file I am trying to execute the needed scripts:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery.min.js"}, function(){
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery-ui.js"}, function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { file: 'script.js' });
});
});
```

Still, in script.js I can't use any Jquery function (error: $ is not defined).

Can anyone please explain me why it's failing, or how it should be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your 'script.js' look like? Are both `$` and `jQuery` undefined?

Comment: Nothing special, the error is thrown at this line:
$(document).mouseup(function (e){ //do some stuff});

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I think you're doing it right. I tried $(document).mouseup(function(e){ console.log('Test'); }); in a Chrome extension on Google Calander and, indeed, when I click I see 'Test' in my console.
Maybe other extensions are interfering? You could try to call `jQuery.noConflict()` and then in your script.js: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) { ... code using the $-sign ... })`

Comment: Thanks for your help T.S. I will try your solution now.
To answer your previous question, $ and jQuery are undefined

Perhaps it has something to do with jquery.min and jquery-ui being used together?

Comment: Don't bother trying, if jQuery is undefined as well, my solution won't work. It really just looks like Chrome cannot find jquery.min.js in your extension folder/package. Are you sure you're including that file?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. 
I am sure that it is included.

Comment: [This solution](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4698118/879266) worked for me, for those still looking

Answer (score 0):

Your manifest.json and background.js look fine. If you have the jquery-file in the root of your extension folder/package, there are only two things I can think of:

1. You are unsetting the $-symbol somewhere in script.js
2. You are not reloading the extension after you made changes:

   Go to chrome://extensions/, find your extension, press 'Reload' (and make sure it's enabled).

   If you are not using the 'Load Unpacked extension' function, you should entirely re-install your extension after you've made changes.

To be very sure that the jQuery file is loaded, open jquery.min.js and add `console.log('jQuery file loaded')` to `jquery.min.js`. If you are not seeing the console message, then maybe `jquery.min.js` is corrupted (try downloading it again).