# Insert a javascript <script> using jquery and chrome extension

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

I am trying to create a simple Chrome extension that takes a javescript from an external provider and simply appends it to the webpage I am viewing. This is for any webpage and not to be selective. When I attempt this nothing loads:

Manifest.json

```html
  {
        "name": "My Extension",
        "version": "0.1.1",
        "description": "Testing Tests!",
        "manifest_version": 2,
        "content_scripts": [
            {
                "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
                "js": ["contentscript.js"]
    
            }
        ]

       

    }
```

contentscript.js

```html
alert("content script");

<script>
var _elev = window._elev || {};(function() {var i,e;i=document.createElement("script"),i.type='text/javascript';i.async=1,i.src="https://static.elev.io/js/v3.js",e=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],e.parentNode.insertBefore(i,e);})();
_elev.account_id = '1234566';
</script>
```

I am new to extensions so help or guidance on how to insert this script to all pages I visit.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Chrome Extensions: How to include jQuery in programatically injected content script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4698118/google-chrome-extensions-how-to-include-jquery-in-programatically-injected-cont)

Comment: I attempted to use this by placing my script in a JS called elevio.js. In this case without the <script> tags. However, it still does nothing.